# Sending current page html back to server through ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

In my application i am sending back the html of my webpage to server through jquery ajax (as i need to store a copy of this page in server).Code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pcontent = document.body.innerHTML;
     var url = new URI().addQuery("pcontent", pcontent);

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "GET", 
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.html());
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert(1);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {  
            if (jqXHR.status) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
            }
            else {
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But this throws an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Request URL Too Long</TITLE>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h2>Request URL Too Long</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.</p>
    </BODY>    
</HTML>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit:from the inputs i got from here i had changed my code like this (changing get to post)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var pcontent = document.body.innerHTML;

    var url = new URI().addQuery("pcontent", pcontent);

    $.ajax({
        url: url, type: "POST"
      , success: function (data) {

          alert(data.html());
      },
        complete: function () {
            alert(1);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

but still the same error exissts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use **post** request not **get** request.

```
var pcontent = document.body.innerHTML;
var url = new URI();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {"pcontent": pcontent},
    success: function (data) {
            alert(data.html());
    },
    complete: function () {
        alert(1);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
        if(jqXHR.status){
            alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
        }else{
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
});
return false;
```

Comment: you need to pass the page content using "data" param. data: {"pcontent": pcontent}, and remove it from the url.

Comment: after trying your code my error moved from old one to new one.
now it throws "Something went wrong".do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the GET variable only supports a limited amount of data, use type: POST instead of type GET

```
$.ajax({
 url: url, type: "POST"
    , success: function (data) {

        alert(data.html());
    },
 complete: function () {
    alert(1);
 },
 error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
 if(jqXHR.status){
    alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
 }else{
    alert("Something went wrong");
 }
 }
});//indentation
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP POST request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST"
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `POST` request. `GET` is limited to 2048 characters in IE, 65,538 in most others.

Comment: changing get to post have not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The GET method sends all data in the URL.

Use the POST method instead.