# Sending the HTML request form to database in one column - flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a web form to capture user data and store it to our database. Have created the webform and using flask to store the data in to our postgres database. I am able to parse the request form and store the values in to individual columns, here is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
from flask import Markup
import sys,os
from functools import wraps
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

USER = os.environ['USER']
PASSWORD = os.environ['PASSWORD']
HOST_NAME = 'servername'
DB_NAME = 'dbname'
DB_SCHEMA = 'dl_schema'
DB_TABLE = 'update_dummytable'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:5432/{databasename}".format(
username=USER,
password=PASSWORD,
hostname=HOST_NAME,
databasename=DB_NAME)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class FormTable(db.Model):

    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_SCHEMA , 'implicit_returning': False}
    __tablename__ = DB_TABLE

    cid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String())
    last_name = db.Column(db.String())
    user_email = db.Column(db.String())
    policy_number = db.Column(db.String())
    formvalue = db.Column(db.String())
    form = db.Column(db.Text())

@app.route('/formupdate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transactions():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    updaterequest = FormTable(first_name=request.form["first_name"], 
last_name=request.form["last_name"], \
    user_email=request.form["user_email"], policy_number=request.form["policy_number"], \
    formvalue=request.form["formvalue"], form= request)
    db.session.add(updaterequest)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "Form Update App"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Above code is working fine, but i am also trying to store the entire request form with user provided values as a html in one of my column in postgres database, i have created a column in my table named "form" as text datatype. But how do I store the entire html with values in that column? When i pass "request.form", it is passing the dictionary with key values but not the html form. Also, when i tried to pass "request" to that column, it throws this error `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'LocalProxy'` I can see the insert query has  `'form': <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/formupdate' [POST]>` , How to pass the entire form with values to database column?

Comment: When you say 'store the entire html' are you trying to store e.g. `<input type="text">`? On your second point, when you try to insert `request` your trying to insert a Python object. You'd need to pickle it to bytes first to store the request in the db.

Comment: Yes I want to store the whole html form, your example is right. how can i do that?

Comment: What are using to render a form in index.html?

Comment: You'll need to use some JavaScript, see [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561935/sending-current-page-html-back-to-server-through-ajax) for inspiration.